# PHP Mail not working when subject or body is a variable

Tags: php, forms, email

-PHP Mail does not function properly when the subject or body is a variable.
For example:

```
//Works
mail("email@domain.com","Subject","Message");

//Does not work
$email = "email@domain.com";
$subject = "Subject";
$message = "Message";
mail($email,$subject,$message);
```

-How can I make this work as I am sending the email taking details from a form.

Comment: Please define _Does not work_

Comment: saying it doesn't work shouldn't be what you should say as a `developer`. Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of the script.

Comment: Do you have any error message? From what I can see here it should work just fine.

Comment: When I put it in a if statement if(mail()){}else{} it does runs the else code.

Comment: I did it does not give any errors

Comment: Did you run the simple `//Works` code in the same IF??

Comment: Yes I did and it worked

Comment: Do you have a mail server configured on your system?

Comment: Yes I do have a mail server configured.